# Why do we use the log-derivative trick before Monte Carlo?

Tags: sampling, expected-value, monte-carlo, logarithm, gradient

I still don't understand how we can **approximate the gradient of an expected value**... Indeed it's impossible to sample points and then to average the gradients of them as **we have only samples...** (How to compute derivatives of samples...?)

**The log-derivative trick** seems to resolve this issue, and i have read that it allows you to compute **Monte Carlo estimate** on expressions that were untractable before...

If we recall the formula :

[image]

I agree that it's impossible to track the first expression with a Monte Carlo as the gradient of p(theta) is **not a distribution**. But why is it now possible to track the expectation of p(theta) * grad(log(p(theta))) ? What is the crucial changement ?

**Thanks a lot for your potential answers !**

Comment: I also struggle with understanding this but I came up with my own understanding which is as follows: In the first case when we approximate the expectation through averageing samples we would do something like SUM_(f(x)_i ) here every f(x)_i sample does not have any information about the underlying probability which therefore cannot be used to calculate any gradients. With the log trick our approximation becomes SUM_(f(x)_i * log_(p(theta)) ) where now every sample has the information of the probability and therefore we can take the derivative of every sample with respect to theta.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It gives me a vague intuition indeed... but it is still not enough to understand it mathematically.

Comment: Did you mean $p(x, \theta)$? Then the gradient could be with respect to $\theta$ while the expectation is taken over $x$. This is the formulation for SGD-based variational Bayes, for example.

Comment: I do not know anything about MC but in other contexts like reinforcement learning they do the same trick. I think the crucial point is that one can write the RHS integral over $\theta$ as an expectation (but with respect to another random variable!) because now there is a term $p(\theta)$ which is not there in the left integral. However, if something is an expectation then we can approximate by using the law of large numbers and so forth.

Comment: There are some errors in the formula. The distribution should be $p(x \mid \theta)$ or $p(x; \theta)$. Also, integration is over $x$; there should be no $d\theta$ term.

Comment: It's a double integration over $\theta$ and over $x$

Comment: Is this problem solved? I am also confused by this.